# Amazon Linux 2 AMI with .NET Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, amazon-ami

I recently spun up an EC2 instance from AWS - "Amazon Linux 2 AMI with .NET Core 2.2" and do not see a webserver running (maybe I'm just missing something here)

Does this mean that despite it having .net core, I need to now just install apache and then do the whole Kestrel and reverse proxy thing in httpd.conf as per this:

https://gooroo.io/GoorooThink/Article/17422/Deploy-ASPNET-Core-Application-On-EC2-Amazon-Linux-Instance/32558#.XZ1NGi-ZPUI

Just needed to do a gut check and make sure there wasn't an easier way before I make a mistake.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Kestrel is promoted as production ready from ASP.NET Core 2.x, which means you can use it as IFS (internet facing server) w/o a reverse proxy... that is unless you need some specific feature which is only available in the reverse proxy of your choice.

Comment: thank you - does this mean I do not need to install apache?

Comment: Depends on your needs. Want run only a single application to run on it and you don't need anything from nginx? yea (Kestrel can't share ports, such as weblistener on windows). if you prefer to have nginx handle ssl, then do it.

Comment: Thanks so how do I "start" Kestrel then? I did a dotnet run and it says it's listening but how do I get the site to work? I tried browsing and it just said page cannot be found and it redirected me to amazon.com

Comment: dotnet run is for testing/development. it compiles sources. you should publish your application and copy the artefacts. see docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21. docs also contain informations how to start it in with systemd https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.0#monitor-the-app